# Api refreshing and getting out of memory error

Tags: android, retrofit2

i'm working on a cricket app 
i,m show live score data with teams and score and show more data which is related to app and none of them contain any image or video file,
i'm refreshing my data( refreshing 5 API simultaneously) in every 5 seconds, after launching the app i got out of memory error

Comment: please post your code

Comment: i'm using handler to refresh the data